# C++ unicode file io

Tags: c++, unicode, file-io

I need a file io library that can give my program a utf-16 (little endian) interface, but can handle files in other encodings, mainly ascii(input only), utf-8, utf-16, utf-32/ucs4 including both little and big endian byte orders.

Having looked around the only library I found was the ICU ustdio.h library.

I did try it however I coudlnt even get that to work with a very simple bit of text, and there is pretty much zero documentation on its useage, only the ICU file reference page which providse no examples and very little detail (eg having made a UFILE from an existing FILE, is it safe to use other functions that take the FILE*? along with several others...).

Also id far rather a c++ library that can give me a wide stream interface over a C style interface...

```
std::wstring str = L"Hello World in UTF-16!\nAnother line.\n";
UFILE *ufile = u_fopen("out2.txt", "w", 0, "utf-16");
u_file_write(str.c_str(), str.size(), ufile);
u_fclose(ufile);
```

output

```
Hello World in UTF-16!਍䄀渀漀琀栀攀爀 氀椀渀攀⸀ഀ
```

hex

```
FF FE 48 00 65 00 6C 00 6C 00 6F 00 20 00 57 00
6F 00 72 00 6C 00 64 00 20 00 69 00 6E 00 20 00
55 00 54 00 46 00 2D 00 31 00 36 00 21 00 0D 0A
00 41 00 6E 00 6F 00 74 00 68 00 65 00 72 00 20
00 6C 00 69 00 6E 00 65 00 2E 00 0D 0A 00
```

EDIT: The correct output on windows would be:

```
FF FE 48 00 65 00 6C 00 6C 00 6F 00 20 00 57 00 
6F 00 72 00 6C 00 64 00 20 00 69 00 6E 00 20 00 
55 00 54 00 46 00 2D 00 31 00 36 00 21 00 0D 00 
0A 00 41 00 6E 00 6F 00 74 00 68 00 65 00 72 00
20 00 6C 00 69 00 6E 00 65 00 2E 00 0D 00 0A 00
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem you see comes from the linefeed conversion. Sadly, it is made at the byte level (after the code conversion) and is not aware of the encoding. IOWs, you have to disable the automatic conversion (by opening the file in binary mode, with the "b" flag) and, if you want 0A00 to be expanded to 0D00A00, you'll have to do it yourself.

You mention that you'd prefer a C++ wide-stream interface, so I'll outline what I did to achieve that in our software:

- Write a std::codecvt facet using an ICU UConverter to perform the conversions.
- Use an std::wfstream to open the file
- imbue() your custom codecvt in the wfstream
- Open the wfstream with the binary flag, to turn off the automatic (and erroneous) linefeed conversion.
- Write a "WNewlineFilter" to perform linefeed conversion on wchars. Use inspiration from [boost::iostreams::newline_filter](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/iostreams/doc/index.html?path=4.2.10.1)
- Use a [boost::iostreams::filtering_wstream](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/iostreams/doc/index.html?path=4.2.5.7) to tie the wfstream and the WNewlineFilter together as a stream.

Answer (score 4):

I successfully worked with the **EZUTF** library posted on CodeProject: 
[High Performance Unicode Text File I/O Routines for C++](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/files/EZUTF.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

[UTF8-CPP](http://utfcpp.sourceforge.net/) gives you conversion between UTF-8, 16 and 32. Very nice and light library.

About ICU, some comments by the UTF8-CPP creator :

> ICU Library. It is very powerful,
> complete, feature-rich, mature, and
> widely used. Also big, intrusive,
> non-generic, and doesn't play well
> with the Standard Library. I
> definitelly recommend looking at ICU
> even if you don't plan to use it.

:)

Answer (score 1):

I think the problems come from the `0D 0A 00` linebreaks. You could try if other linebreaks like `\r\n` or using LF or CR alone do work (best bet would be using `\r`, I suppose)

EDIT: It seems `0D 00 0A 00` is what you want, so you can try

```
std::wstring str = L"Hello World in UTF-16!\15\12Another line.\15\12";
```

Comment: Tried that sort of stuff, \r works, \n is replaced by a broken \r\n, so \r\n in my string becomes 0D 00 0D 0A 00

Comment: Yes, I thought this would happen with \r\n. I even guess 0D 00 0A 00 would be bad because you would get 2 newlines instead of one.

Comment: "(best bet would be using \r, I suppose)" Id rather use a library that is able to write files that are valid on the given platform, ie \r\n for dos/windows, \n for linux and \r for mac. Apart from the ar alone is likely to break lots of other stuff that uses the files that are expecting valid little endian utf-16 files with windows line breaks...

Comment: "0D 00 0A 00" is correct on windows, so thats exactly what I want it to output (and be able to read) as a new line. \r or \n are not correct for windows files.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the iconv ([libiconv](http://www.gnu.org/software/libiconv)) library.